# Financial News API

Tags: api

Any free/paid **API to get financial news** either world-wide / country specific.

Comment: Have you considered Newsriver (https://newsriver.io)? It's API allows to search for online news articles. Newsriver covers a large number of sources, it provides access to standardised structured news and comes with an extended search syntax based on Lucene query syntax.
News article are enriched with metadata information like the article category, you could used it to search for financial news only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take it off **Yahoo** as an RSS feed:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/topstories
```

Comment: I don't believe this rss feed has been updated since 2014

Answer (score 2):

[**Reuters** News API](http://mashable.com/2008/05/12/reuters-ap/) for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

[**NewsCloud** Web Services](http://www.newscloud.com/learn/apidocs/) has an open API -- commercial use is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

[MyAllies Companies Breaking News](http://www.myallies.com) with JSON output

Example:

http://www.myallies.com/api for all companies recent news.

Or

http://www.myallies.com/api/amzn for Amazon news.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend financial news aggregator CityFALCON which recently launched their API. They collects news from all around the internet and score them according to the proprietary algorithm. So there is a possibility to sort news not in chronological order but by their relevancy. For more information you can visit this page http://www.cityfalcon.com/blog/investments/financial-news-api-widget/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try www.xignite.com. They support SOAP and building a REST API that you can get news from.